# How can I fix the time in Windows Powershell?

Tags: powershell, time

Windows powershell gives me the following incorrect date and time:

```
PS C:\Users\jroy-adm> Get-ADUserLastLogon jroy-hm
jroy-hm last logged on at: 12/31/1600 4:00:00 PM
PS C:\Users\jroy-adm>
```

The operating system has the correct date and time.

Answer (score 3):

Powershell doesn't have its own time. It uses the OS time.

That returned time means the user has never logged in. It is the Active directory NULL timestamp

Comment: No...no, I'm pretty sure 'ol jroy logged in at precisely 4PM back on that blustery afternoon in 1600.